# What's inside the Android A/B-Update payload.bin?

Tags: security, ota-update, 8.0-oreo

I am using Android 8 for an embedded device, with Android Verified Boot 2.0 secured via HW-keys, and A/B OTA update (no streaming). I want to make sure that the software on the device is tightly secured; however, I'm having a hard time to trace the individual steps the update performs. One hint would be the metadata contained in the update `payload.bin`.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no documentation on the `payload.bin` file format and its contents. Is there an official documentation for the file format? Or is there a crisp piece of code (e.g., build tools( that I haven't found out about yet?
The tools for "dumping" `payload.bin` give me the contained images, but not the metadata.
What I'd like to understand is the following:

- Which parts of `payload.bin` are signed with which key?
- Are there parts that are not signed?
- Which additional verification elements are contained in `payload.bin`, and how does the `update_engine` use them? For example: there are hashes to verify the target partitions following the installation
- For a differential update, there must be a means to ensure that the system on the device is exactly the one used as source for the update diff. Where are those hash-values?
- How about a full update - can the updater ensure that the update is installed only atop a specific version on the device?

I apologise if I have missed sources that answer these questions. The books about Android system programming I came across are outdated by now. Any pointers to relevant documentation beyond the basic Android docs would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What I understand is that Google moved A/B updates infrastructure from their closed-source Chrome OS to AOSP. But they want OEMs use Google's A/B update client (integrated in Play Service) and hence Google's update servers along with cloud hosting. After all it's about business. There is no clear documentation available but for tech-savvy souls the complete code is available in `update_engine`, enough to understand and implement from scratch. This is more a development related question.

Comment: "OEMs not using Google's OTA infrastructure will be able to reuse the AOSP system code but will need to supply their own client." https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/ab#overview

Answer (score 0):

build tool for A/B payload.bin is a call chain:

[ota_from_target_files.py](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/make/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files.py) -> `GenerateAbOtaPackage()` -> `payload.Generate()` -> `brillo_update_payload.sh` -> [generate_delta_main.cc](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:system/update_engine/payload_generator/generate_delta_main.cc)

---

payload file format - [system/update_engine/update_engine/update_metadata.proto](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:system/update_engine/update_metadata.proto)